# Prolog problems

Tags: file-io, prolog

I use swi prolog. My code runs for first line but it doesn't run the others.

```
 see(Data), //open file to read
   repeat,
    readln(A), //read line from file 
    write(A),
   A\==end_of_file,!.
```

I get an unexpected end of file error. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

readln/1 is not a in the swi-prolog manual so maybe you should include the code for that too.
assuming that it does what you say, the code should probably be:

```
 see(Data), //open file to read
   repeat,
   readln(A), //read line from file 
   write(A),
   A=end_of_file,!.
```

the repeat/0 "structure" works like repeat...until

on a side note, i would prefer recursive solution...like

```
io(end_of_file):-
    write(end_of_file).
io(_):-
    readln(A),
    write(A),
    io(A).
```

feels more declarative.